# Laravel Paypal where does the Frontend Coming from

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Im trying to implement paypal for ages, my major problem is, that i dont understand where the paypal login is coming from.

https://websolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-integrate-paypal-payment-gateway-in-laravel
Here ive absolutly no clue where the magic happens.

https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-58-paypal-integration-tutorialexample.html
Here is suggest it is the line

```
return redirect($response['paypal_link']); ?
```

Is that true? What does this line?

The problem for me is to undersand how can a frontendpop up work, when there is no paypal-javascript-file implemted in one of the blade files and which line of code starts the login-adress-payment etc. paypal part in the frontend.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what that refers to specifically, perhaps a rel:approve href returned from one of the PayPal APIs.

However, I can tell you that the best PayPal integration (in Laravel or otherwise) uses **no redirects**. At all.

Instead, follow the [Set up standard payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/set-up-standard-payments/) guide and make two routes on your server, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return only JSON data (no HTML or text). Within the second route, when the capture response is successful, store its resulting payment details in your database (particularly `purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id`, the PayPal transaction ID) and perform any necessary business logic (such as sending confirmation emails or reserving product) *before* forwarding your return JSON to the frontend.

Pair those two routes with the JS frontend approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server